# I'm using Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10

I had a problem with my monitor shutting down and then restarting.  A tech fixed it by adding Malwareby anti-virus program, but most of my bookmark icons disappeared.  How do I refresh them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.  If you were using Chrome, and you now no longer have bookmarks, it sounds like the individual wiped your Chrome profile.  If your Chrome profile has been wiped, and you were not synching your profile to your Google account, then your bookmarks are gone.

Comment: Bookmark icons can refreshed every time you use the link, click a link with no icon and see if it refreshes the icon when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Joice, it seems like you have multiple problems:

> my monitor shutting down and then restarting

You probably mean your Computer or Notebook - i haven't seen a simple Monitor doing so. Your Computer just made a restart, this could have various reasons, including this one:

Depending on your system configuration, windows 10 restarts after installing updates without too much asking if it's okay for the user to do so.

So, most likely this restart was a completely normal thing to happen. 
Check your windows settings ("Update and security"), to see and set how your computer behaves when updates need to be installed.

> tech fixed it by adding Malwareby anti-virus program

Oh well... if someone installs a program like this on your machine just because it made a restart and remembering the mentioned behaviour of windows 10: Don't call that person a "tech".

Malwarebytes can be helpful **if** there is some problem with "Malware" (hence the name) on your computer, but just having a restart ist **not** a sign for problems like this. Not when using Windows 10, at least.

> most of my bookmark icons disappeared

To me, it seems like this could be a result of using Malwarebytes. Could be anything else, too.

As you're not providing any helpful information, let's suggest this:

**Chrome Bookmarks Recovery Tool**

https://rongjiecomputer.github.io/chrome/bookmark-recovery/#windows

...good luck!